# Can you assign a the value of a rich data type into a variable in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, types

I am trying to save the ticker symbol I derived using a Rich data type (I am not sure if I said it correctly) from B2 to a variable.

[image]

I used this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim Ticker As String
        
        If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
            Ticker = Activesheet.Range("B2").Value
            MsgBox Ticker
        End If

End Sub
```

It happens when I make changes to A2.

I tried to convert it into text or string and it does not work. I assigned the variable as a Variant and String, but still, it won't work. Error is saying "Run time error'13' Type mismatch. But I cannot figure out where I did wrong.

When I debug it, Ticker = ""

I googled around and I cannot find an answer. Is it possible though?

Comment: Please edit your question and include code that you have attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** when you change the rich data type in `A2`, Excel starts retrieving the ticker symbol in `B2` via `=A2.[Ticker symbol]`. Fetching such data might take a short while, and while the request is pending, `B2` will show as `#FIELD!`. While in this state, `B2.Value` will be read as an error, so that your code will bounce on `Ticker = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value`, since the variable is dimmed as `String`. This is why you get the "Type mismatch" error.

**Solution**: Build a slight delay into your code that will give Excel sufficient time to retrieve the requested data. We can use a `Do While Loop` for this. Define 2 booleans:

1. First boolean checks `IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("B2"))`
2. Second boolean functions as a timer

Exit the loop when either of these booleans becomes `False`. You want to include the second boolean to ensure that you do not end up in an infinite loop. This might otherwise happen if the value in `B2` will always remain `#FIELD`, because you didn't supply a valid entry in `A2`.

Something like the following should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim Ticker As String
    Dim fieldError As Boolean, onTime As Boolean
    Dim endTime As Date
    
    'using Target.Text <> "" rather than Target.Value <> "", since the latter will throw an error
    'if the range contains a 'rich data type'
    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveSheet.Range("A2")) Is Nothing And Target.Text <> "" Then

        'set timeframe to wait for response, set to 1 second here
            'we want to check: if "#FIELD!" hasn't changed into a proper value after 1 second
            'then data in A2 is probably nonsense: exit loop
            
        endTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        
        'set Booleans
        onTime = True
        fieldError = True
        
        'enter Do While Loop
        Do While fieldError And onTime 'continue until
            
            If IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("B2")) Then
            Else
                'B2 (no longer) an error, switch bool to False to exit loop
                fieldError = False
            End If
            
            'bool to False after time out to exit loop
            onTime = Now < endTime
            
        Loop
        
        'In case of Error, probably incorrect input in A2
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
        Ticker = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value

ErrorHandling:

        Debug.Print "A2.Text = " & ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Text & "), " & _
        "ticker = " & Ticker & ", fieldError = " & fieldError & ", onTime = " & onTime
        
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'do stuff (you probably got a correct response, but it's still an error
            Debug.Print "Entered ErrorHandling"
            Err.Number = 0
        End If

        Debug.Print "------"

    Else

    End If

End Sub
```

To exemplify, below you see a loop in action that populates `A2` with a reference to items in the range `LIST` successively and tries to retrieve the ticker. Notice the output in the immediate window: for "AA", "AAPL" and "AMZN" we are exiting the loop on `fieldError = False` (ticker found). For "NONSENSE" we are exiting on `onTime = False` (no ticker: we timed out).

[image: example rich data type stocks]

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this:

```
Range(Cells(9, 18), Cells(FilaEG - 1, 18)).ConvertToLinkedDataType ServiceID:=268435456, LanguageCulture:="en-US"
Cells(i, 15) = "=R" & Trim(Str(i)) & ".Price"
```

Comment: there are two lines, the first convert the names in stock data type , the second begins in Cells